# Create DSL to query postgres json similar to ActiveRecord's where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

In ActiveRecord we can do `where(my_attribute: value)` for an attribute in a column.

That's not possible yet with attributes defined in a json column, instead it would look like this:

```
where("document->>'my_attribute' = ?", value)
```

If we assume that my model only has one json column, `document`, would it be possible to create a custom chainable query for that column looking something like this:

```
dwhere(my_attribute: value)
```

Comment: have you use hstore on postgres?

Comment: No, jsonb. `t.jsonb :document, null: false, default: '{}'`

Comment: to search over serialized fields you can use hstore

Comment: https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore

Comment: Thanks but that functionality is already built in to Rails4. I wanted to know if and how one could create a query more similar to ActiveRecord.

Comment: you can try, just compare two resulted SQLs

Comment: No it is not possible. AR query interface do not support things like this.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I've come up with:

```
scope :dwhere, -> (key, value) { where("document ->> '#{key}' = '?'", value) }
```

To use like this:

```
MyModel.dwhere(key, value)
```